# Entity Framework 4.3.1 Migrations - enable automatic migration and creating a new database in the same time

Tags: entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I have played with Entity Framework 4.3 migrations for some time now, but I have trouble achieving the next behavior: In case my code runs on an existing database, I want the database to be migrated automatically to the latest version, but in case the database doesn't exist, the database should be created automatically from the migrations.

I think the problems is related to the first migration that you create. If you create the first migration using -IgnoreChanges parameter (or manually delete them as explained here: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/using-ef-migrations-with-an-existing-database/), you will not be able to use migrations in order to create a new table using the DbMigrator class. because you don't have the initial migration. If you create the first migration without using -IgnoreChanges, than the migration of the existing database will not be possible. Does anybody has any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So you have existing database and you want to use migrations on that database and in the same time you want to support database creation by migrations in case of new deployment?

It looks like little bit unsupported use case. The simplest in this case (not tested) would be either conditional compilation or conditional migration driven by some AppSettings key. It means creating initial migration as if you don't have the database and modify Up method to:

```
public override void Up() {
    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewDatabaseRequired"] == "true") {
        // Here is generated content
    }
}
```

or

```
public override void Up() {
#if NewDatabaseRequired
    // Here is generated content
#endif
}
```

There is plenty of other  more complicated options including scripting your current database, modify the script to end if tables already exist, add a script as a resource to your migration assembly and execute the script in the `Up` method generated with `-IgnoreChanges`.

As another option you can open additional database connection and check if tables from migration already exists (by querying `sys.tables` view in SQL Server). This will not need generated script.